# regex find long and short vowels

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words in various languages, that make use of more than the usual five vowels (a,e,i,o,u). I am using regex to divide these words into syllables after a vowel-consonant pair. For words like "ahotnikil" I use `re.match("^[a|e|i|y|o|u|}|@]", word)` to get the correct segmentation, `['a', 'hot', 'ni', 'kil']`
But my re.match expression does not find all the vowels, for words such as:

> ɔčolwun    ['ɔčol', 'wun']

> duktəwurəji    ['du', 'ktəwu', 'rəji']

> śīnici ['śīnici']

the "ɔ, ə, ī" are not recognized. I tried copying them into the expression but still, they are not recognized. I used the follwoing code to check the encoding type of the file (output: {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''})

```
import chardet
with open(filename, 'rb') as rawdata:    
    result = chardet.detect(rawdata.read(100000))
result
```

So then I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
re.match("[aeiyou}@]|ɔ|ə|ī", word)
```

Note: `re.match` will look for matches at the start of string by default. If you need to detect these chars anywhere inside a word, use `re.search`.

*Details*:

- `[aeiyou}@]` - a char from the `aeiyou}@` set
- `|` - or
- `ɔ` - a `ɔ` char
- `|` - or
- `ə` - a `ə` char
- `|` - or
- `ī` - a `ī` char

Comment: I should specify perhaps that the characters are in a column dataframe? Unfortunately, even with what you suggest @Wiktor, the issue is that it skips these characters completely as if it doesn't see them